# Smooth approximation of Hölder functions "from below"

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory

We assume that we have a $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function $f$ on an interval $[0,1].$

I am wondering if there exists an explicit construction of a sequence $f_{n} \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ such that

$$\lVert f-f_n\rVert_{C^{\beta}([0,1])} \le \frac{1}{n}$$

for fixed $\beta<\alpha$ and $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \le \lvert f(x)\rvert$ on $[0,1]$. The usual convolution idea does not respect the last condition. In an earlier post, I mistakingly took $\beta=\alpha.$

Comment: Looks like you can get away with first taking the composition $G\circ f$ where $G(x)=0$ of $[-\delta,\delta]$, $x-\delta$ for $x>\delta$ and $x+\delta$ for $x<-\delta$ and then convolving this composition with a smooth narrow bump, cannot you?

Comment: As @fedja suggested or also: first approximate $f$ with smooth $f_n$ in $C^\gamma$ with $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$ and then take $f \wedge f_n$ and so on. I am using the fact that a Lipschitz map $F$ defines a continuous map $u \mapsto F(u)$ from $C^\gamma \to C^\beta$ (if you want $\beta=\gamma$ you need $F \in C^1$). You need also to write $f \wedge g=(f-g)^-+f$.

Comment: @fedja : I am afraid that where $f$ was $0$ (or very close to $0$) (and remained so after the composition with $G$) it might be not necessary that the (near) vanishing property is preserved after the convolution.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Can you explain what you mean by "so on"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry for being unclear. Having $f_n$, use $(f \wedge f_n) \vee (-f)$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : But when you truncate, can't you lose the smoothness?

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are right...this is only Lipschitz approximation

Comment: @IosifPinelis No, sorry again, since I truncate with $f$ everything is lost...I mixed all things

Comment: @fedja : Looking at the answer below, it seems one needs to sort out small intervals, to avoid their clustering. Also, it seems one needs to sort not only the values of $f$ but also the values of its argument.

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos : Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: @IosifPinelis please excuse the delay. I just wanted to wait a bit, as I thought fedja might have something to add. As you pointed out, your nice answer in that was rather intricate in the end and not as simple as the argument that fedja seemed to have initially thought about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal J}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$Yes, such a construction exists.

Indeed, take any real $\ep>0$. For a real $C\ge0$ and $\al\in(0,1]$, let us say that a function $g$ is $(C,\al)$-Hölder on a set $S\subseteq[0,1]$ if $|g(y)-g(x)|\le C|y-x|^\al$ for all $x,y$ in $S$.

Without loss of generality (wlog), the function $f$ is $(1,\al)$-Hölder on $[0,1]$.

Let $Z:=\{z\in I:=[0,1]\colon f(z)=0\}$ and $N:=I\setminus Z$. Wlog, $\{0,1\}\in Z$ (otherwise, extend $f$ appropriately to an interval $[A,B]\supset I$ so that $f(A)=0=f(B)$ and then shrink the interval $[A,B]$ to $I$). So, $N=\bigcup_{J\in\J}J$ for some (countable) set $\J$ of pairwise disjoint nonempty open subintervals of $I$.

It is enough to construct a smooth function $f_\ep$ such that for each $J\in\J$
\begin{equation*}
    \|f-f_\ep\|_{C^\be(J)}\le100\ep \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    |f_\ep|\le|f|\text{ on } J. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

To begin such a construction, take any real $\de>0$. Let $\J_\de$ denote the set of all intervals $J\in\J$ of length $>\de$. Of course, the set $\J_\de$ is finite. Let
\begin{equation*}
    f_\ep(x):=0\text{ for }x\in I\setminus\bigcup_{J\in\J_\de}J. 
\end{equation*}

If $\de$ is small (which will be henceforth assumed), then on $I\setminus\bigcup_{J\in\J_\de}J$ the function $f-f_\ep=f$ is small and $(1,\al)$-Hölder. So, $f-f_\ep=f$ is $(\de_1,\be)$-Hölder on $I\setminus\bigcup_{J\in\J_\de}J$ for a small $\de_1$. This follows because $|y-x|^\al<<|y-x|^\be$ if $\be\in(0,\al)$ (as given) and $|y-x|<<1$, whereas $|y-x|^\al\asymp|y-x|^\be\asymp1$ if $|y-x|\asymp1$. (We write $E<<F$ if $E=o(F)$, $E\ll F$ if $E=O(F)$, and $E\asymp F$ if $E\ll F\ll E$.)

We shall build the function $f_\ep$ separately on each interval $J=(a,b)\in\J_\de$, in such a manner that
\begin{equation*}
\text{$f_\ep=0$ near the endpoints of $J$. } \tag{30}\label{30} 
\end{equation*}
Then the smoothness of $f_\ep$ on each interval $J\in\J$ will be enough for the smoothness of $f_\ep$ on the entire interval $I$.

Take indeed any interval $J\in\J_\de$.
Note that (i) $f(a)=0=f(b)$ and (ii) either $f>0$ on $(a,b)$ or $f<0$ on $(a,b)$. Wlog, $f>0$ (on $(a,b)$). Moreover, $f$ is continuous. So, $M:=f(x_*)\ge f(x)$ for some $x_*\in J$ and all $x\in J$.
For any $c\in(0,M]$, the points
\begin{equation*}
    x_+(c):=\min\{x\in[x_*,b)\colon f(x)\le c\},\quad x_-(c):=\max\{x\in(a,x_*]\colon f(x)\le c\}  
\end{equation*}
are well defined. Moreover,
\begin{equation*}
    f\ge c\text{ on }J_c:=[x_-(c),x_+(c)],\quad f(x_\pm(c))=c. \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}

Let
\begin{equation*}
    g:=(f-c)1_{J_c}. \tag{45}\label{45}
\end{equation*}
Then $g$ is $(1,\al)$-Hölder on $\R$ and hence so is
\begin{equation*}
    g_\eta:=g*K_\eta, \tag{47}\label{47}
\end{equation*}
where, for each $\eta\in(0,\de)$, we let $K_\eta$ be any smooth nonnegative function supported on the interval $[-\eta,\eta]$ such that $\int K_\eta=1$.

Moreover, for $x\in J_c=[x_-(c),x_+(c)]$,
\begin{align}
    g_\eta(x)&=\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)(f(x-u)-c)1(x-u\in J_c) \notag \\ 
    &\le\eta^\al+\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)(f(x)-c)1(x-u\in J_c) \notag \\ 
    &\le\eta^\al+(f(x)-c)\le f(x) \notag 
\end{align}
assuming that $\eta^\al\le c$, which will be indeed assumed henceforth.

Further, for $x\in[x_+(c),x_+(c)+\eta]$,
\begin{align}
    g_\eta(x)&=\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)(f(x-u)-c)1(x-u\in J_c) \notag \\ 
&=\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)(f(x-u)-f(x_+(c))1(x-u\in J_c) \notag \\ 
&\le\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)(x_+(c)-(x-u))^\al 1(x-u\in [x_-(c),x_+(c)]) \notag \\ 
&\le\int_{-\eta}^\eta du\,K_\eta(u)\eta^\al 1(x-u\in [x_-(c),x_+(c)]) 
\le\eta^\al. \notag  
\end{align}
On the other hand, again for $x\in[x_+(c),x_+(c)+\eta]$, we have $f(x)\ge f(x_+(c))-(x-x_+(c))^\al\ge c-\eta^\al\ge\eta^\al\ge g_\eta(x)$ assuming that
\begin{equation*}
    2\eta^\al\le c, \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
which will be indeed assumed henceforth.
Similarly, $g_\eta(x)\le\eta^\al$ for $x\in[x_-(c)-\eta,x_-(c)]$ given \eqref{50}.
Also, $g_\eta(x)=0\le f(x)$ for $x\in J\setminus J_c$.
We conclude that
\begin{equation}
    g_\eta\le f\text{ on }J. 
\end{equation}

So, letting
\begin{equation*}
    f_\ep:=g_\eta\text{ on }J=(a,b), \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{equation*}
we see that $f_\ep$ is smooth on $J=(a,b)$, and conditions \eqref{20} and \eqref{30} hold.
Moreover, $g_\eta$ is $(1,\al)$-Hölder on $\R$ and hence $f_\ep$ is $(1,\al)$-Hölder on $J$.

So, it remains to check that $f_\ep$ is uniformly close to $f$ on $J$, also uniformly in $J\in\J_\de$.

By \eqref{45}, on $J_c$ the function $g$ is uniformly close to $f$ if $c$ is small enough, which will be henceforth assumed.

Also, on $J\setminus J_c$ we have $0\le f\le\max((b-x_+(c))^\al,(x_-(c)-a)^\al)$, which is small (since $c$ was assumed to be small), and hence $f$ is close to $g$ (which is $0$ on $J\setminus J_c$). So, $g$ is uniformly close to $f$ on $J$, uniformly in $J\in\J_\de$.

Finally, because $\eta$ is small, and in view of \eqref{60} and \eqref{47}, we conclude that indeed $f_\ep$ is uniformly close to $f$ on $J$, uniformly in $J\in\J_\de$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Does your proof give that for any continuous and positive $f$, there exists a smooth $g$ such that $0 \leq g \leq f$ poitwise? Also that does not look obvious to me (unless $f$ is strictly positive).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : I don't think that this proof implies the result you mention, for continuous (rather than Hölder-continuous) functions. However, I think the just-continuous case should be somewhat simpler.

Comment: For continuous $f \geq 0$ this simple construction works. If $M$ is the maximum of $f$, $K=\{f \geq M/2\}$, $V=\{f >M/4\}$ let $g$ be smooth with compact support in $V$ with $0 \leq g \leq M/4$ and $g=M/4$ in $K$. Then $0 \leq g \leq f$ and $f-g \leq (3/4)M$. Iterating this argument one finds $0 \leq f-(g_1+\dots g_n) \leq (3/4)^n M$ (in the previous comment I forgot to say that $f-g$ should be small).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Nice argument!